# CronJob created as job in k8s 1.19.11

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have what seems like an API issue that results in not being to be able to create a job from a cron job.

I have a CronJob Helm file using the API like so:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
```

Deploying that with helm works just fine.

Then after it is deployed I attempt to create a job using that cronjob like so:

```
 kubectl create job $(helm-release-name) --from=cronjob/connector-config
```

This used to create the job based on the chart above. Now however, since upgrading to 1.19.11 I instead get this error:

```
##[error]error: unknown object type *v1beta1.CronJob
commandOutput
##[error]The process 
'/opt/hostedtoolcache/kubectl/1.22.1/x64/kubectl' failed with exit code 1
```

If I change the api in the Helm chart to this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
```

Then the Helm chart fails to deploy.

```
UPGRADE FAILED: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "CronJob" in version 
"batch/v1"
```

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: which version of K8s you are using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CronJobs is generally available (GA) in Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) version 1.21 and later.

the version you should use `apiVersion: batch/v1`

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/

> CronJobs was promoted to general availability in Kubernetes v1.21. If
> you are using an older version of Kubernetes, please refer to the
> documentation for the version of Kubernetes that you are using, so
> that you see accurate information. Older Kubernetes versions do not
> support the batch/v1 CronJob API.

You can check the support Kubernetes API versions using

```
kubectl api-resources OR kubectl api-versions
```

you can also try

```
kubectl explain <Resource type>

kubectl explain cronjob
```